# How to delete or untrust all root certificates in OSX?

Tags: macos, security, osx-lion, certificate, ssl-certificate

I right clicked on all the root certificates, but it doesn't allow me to delete them, or to untrust them all at once. How can this be done? Is it safe to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to delete all root certificates?

Comment: There's lot of suspicious looking ones. Do I need them?